# most used frontend framework and which is more compatible with backend framework

Tags: vue.js

according to Javascript there are three major frontend framework like react, angular and vue.js which is easy to understand, learn and implement. which is more compatible with Python Django backend framework

Answer (score 1):

Actually, frontend frameworks do not care about the backend whether it is Django, Node, or another stack the main point is the use case. When you want build applications witch need image processing or data analysis you may switch to django but maybe for a weblog, you choose Node.js so it depends on the use-case to which stack should we use for the backend.

Comment: okay got it.....